# Django + Celery with AWS SQS - Running on localhost instead of AWS and not getting messages

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-sqs

Hello I am running Django and Celery on aws SQS, but it appears that AWS is not getting the messages. But the tasks are being executed:

```
Please specify a different user using the --uid option.

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

  uid=uid, euid=euid, gid=gid, egid=egid,

 -------------- celery@ba117e7c453f v4.4.0 (cliffs)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Linux-4.9.125-linuxkit-x86_64-with 2020-02-26 20:21:14
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         config:0x7f10e26fada0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqs://XXXXXXXXXXXXX:**@localhost//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . config.celery.debug_task
  . project.orders.tasks.create_log_test

[2020-02-26 20:21:14,909: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqs://XXXXXXXXXXXX:**@localhost//
[2020-02-26 20:21:15,327: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ba117e7c453f ready.
[2020-02-26 20:21:32,895: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: project.orders.tasks.create_log_test[d4c20965-b1f2-47dd-b8a8-6f9cbe35be29]
[2020-02-26 20:21:53,648: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task project.orders.tasks.create_log_test[d4c20965-b1f2-47dd-b8a8-6f9cbe35be29] succeeded in 20.695041599974502s: None
[2020-02-26 20:22:39,801: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: project.orders.tasks.create_log_test[1d1b0892-078c-480c-ab7a-87662fd18ba3]
[2020-02-26 20:22:41,622: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: project.orders.tasks.create_log_test[6e755a91-b737-4e09-b910-03e84fd91c32]
[2020-02-26 20:22:43,237: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: project.orders.tasks.create_log_test[5fe1f145-a6d3-45d3-8ada-b1c636ee201c]
[2020-02-26 20:22:44,506: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: project.orders.tasks.create_log_test[84da9170-7861-488d-936f-5d3738e11af4]
[2020-02-26 20:22:47,056: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: project.orders.tasks.create_log_test[748dda1c-3b6d-40e6-b13b-637ea765dd72]
```

And on AWS console:
[image]

This is my settings.py:

```
BROKER_URL = "sqs://{access_key}:{secret_key}@".format(
    access_key=quote(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, safe=""),
    secret_key=quote(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, safe=""),
)

BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "visibility_timeout": 60,  # 1 minutes
    "polling_interval": 5,  # 5 seconds
    "queue_name_prefix": "sqs-celery-example-",
}

# CELERY namespaced
CELERY_BROKER_URL = BROKER_URL
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "default"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Solved! The problem was that i didn't put the URL after the "@".

```
BROKER_URL = "sqs://{access_key}:{secret_key}@sqs.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/XXXX/XXXX.fifo".format(
    access_key=quote(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, safe=""),
    secret_key=quote(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, safe=""),
)
```

Comment: Am also facing the same issue, but am using redis as my broker 